# Abstract properties in an abstract class. Whats the point?

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-class

I have just begun to use abstract classes but i'm wondering a bit about the use of abstract properties in abstract classes.
Why whould you make a property abstract in an already abstract class? The property will be exposed no matter if its abstract or not. In what cases is it an advantage to make the properties abstract in an abstract class?
Maybe a bit stupid/basic question, but so far I have not yet had the situation where I said to myself "uhhh this exact property should be abstract in this abstract class".

Consider this example.. Would you make any of the properties abstract? And why?

```
public abstract class BaseError
{
    public string Title { get; set; } = "";
    public string Description { get; set; } = "";
    public Exception Exception { get; set; }
    private DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    public BaseError()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking why would you convert any of the properties in the example into equivalent abstract properties? Edit: It could be argued that it is to be open for extension, yet I don't forsee the use in your particular example.

Answer (score 3):

It should be noted that you don't have [abstract properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd3z1377.aspx) in the example. Those are [auto properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx); they have a hidden backing field.

---

## Abstract Properties

Properties are compounds of get and set methods, they are not required to be implemented simply by setting and reading a backing field.

The derived class may decide to add validation to the property, to store it in something else than a backing field, to add an event when the property changes value, implement it as constant, throw exception, etc.

---

To define an abstract property, follow this example:

```
public abstract double x
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Notice the `abstract` keyword.

Using an abstract property forces the derived class to provide an implementation using the `override` keyword.

---

## Auto Properties

Auto properties are properties implemented with a hidden backing field. Similarly to abstract properties they don't have getter or setter bodies.

Taken from your example, this is an auto property:

```
public string Title { get; set; } = "";
```

Here, the compiler will generate a hidden backing field to store the value of the property, and it will be set to `""` on construction (when an object of the class is created).

Auto properties, has advantages over public fields. In particular if a future implementation needs to change the behavior of the property they can do so without altering the interface of the class.

Recommended reading: [Properties vs. Public Variables](https://blog.codinghorror.com/properties-vs-public-variables/)